# Is alternative available in back end for drush migrate-import "ID"?

Tags: 8, importing-exporting

I have been migrating the contents using the migrating source csv, tools and plus modules

As followed the instruction, I have to use the drush command **drush migrate-import 'ID'** to complete the migration process.

Is there any option available in backend instead of using the drush command.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this, without using the Drush Commands

> drush migrate-import 'ID'

After the import process,

```
$migration = "Migration ID"
$migration = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.migration')->createInstance($migration_id);
$executable = new MigrateExecutable($migration, new MigrateMessage());
$executable->import();
```

If you dont want to use Drush Commands, then Create the custom module and use this above command.